# How to check a geopoint is within some geographical area

Tags: android

I want to make an android application in which,i want to know my current location is within which specific police station.First tell me is it possible or not ,if possible give some idea

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Location`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class. Create two Location objects. One for your current location and another for the location of the police station. Then you can use the method `distanceTo` of `Location` to get the distance between you and the police station. You can assume that you are within the police station if the distance is less than a threshold you defined.